# Correct way to split name

Tags: database, forms, user-experience

What is the correct way to split full name field?

For example I have a full name field with value:
"Dede Dada Gege Jojo"

And I want to do split on the backend.

Which one is correct one and why?

1. First name: "Dede", Last name: "Dada Gege Jojo"
2. First name: "Dede Dada Gege", Last name: "Jojo"

Answer (score 0):

Neither is guaranteed to be correct. If you want correct, give the user the opportunity to enter their names (of which there may be more than two, or in some cases [there might only be one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person)) in separate fields.

Also see [the classic article *Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for a variety of other things that can go wrong here.